# Compiler error when catching templated exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, exception, c++-cli

This is my generic exception and its base class, written in native C++:

```
class DRAException : public std::exception {
public:
    DRAException( const std::string& what ) : std::exception( what.c_str() ) {}
    virtual ~DRAException( ){}
};

template<typename T>
class InvalidArgumentException : public DRAException{
    static std::string CreateErrorMessage( const std::string& argName, T value, boost::optional<T> min, boost::optional<T> max ){
        std::string& errorMessage = "Invalid argument value for " + argName + ": " + StringUtils::toString(value);
        if( min.is_initialized() )
            errorMessage += ". Min value: " + StringUtils::toString( min.get() );
        if( max.is_initialized() )
            errorMessage += ". Max value: " + StringUtils::toString( max.get() );
        return errorMessage;
    }
public:
    InvalidArgumentException( const std::string& argName, T value, boost::optional<T> min, boost::optional<T> max ) :
        DRAException( CreateErrorMessage(argName, value, min, max) ){ }
};
```

In a C++/CLI assembly, I define a macro which maps native exceptions to managed ones:

```
#define BEGIN_EXCEPTION_GUARDED_BLOCK \
    try {
#define END_EXCEPTION_GUARDED_BLOCK \
    \
    //Other catch clauses omitted for brevity's sake
    } catch( DRAExceptions::InvalidArgumentException ex ) { \
        throw gcnew System::ArgumentException( msclr::interop::marshal_as<System::String^>( ex.what() ) ); \
    }
```

And then I use it like this:

```
void MCImage::FindOptimalLut( Single% fWindow, Single% fLevel ) {
    BEGIN_EXCEPTION_GUARDED_BLOCK
    pin_ptr<Single> pWindow = &fWindow, pLevel = &fLevel;
    m_pNativeInstance->findOptimalLut( *pWindow, *pLevel );
    END_EXCEPTION_GUARDED_BLOCK
}
```

But when trying to build the last piece of code, I get this error:

```
Image.cpp(72): error C2955: 'DRAExceptions::InvalidArgumentException' : use of class template requires template argument list
4>          d:\svn.dra.workingcopy\mcommon\../CommonCppLibrary/CustomExceptions.h(50) : see declaration of 'DRAExceptions::InvalidArgumentException'
4>Image.cpp(72): error C2316: 'DRAExceptions::InvalidArgumentException' : cannot be caught as the destructor and/or copy constructor are inaccessible
```

I can't specialize my templated class in the catch clause because that would defeat the purpose of catching all specializations regardless of type. As for the other error, both constructor and destructor are public, so I don't get it. How can I work around this?

PS: I just started using the Boost libraries, so a Boost-specific solution is acceptable

Comment: Note: std::exception() does not technically have a constructor that takes a string. You are using a broken version of the standard library. You should change std::exception and use std::runtime_error instead to make your code standard compliant. See **18.8.1 Class exception [exception]** and **19.2 Exception classes [std.exceptions]**

Comment: Good to know that. It's weird to see that in Visual Studio 2010, anyway. Perhaps they left it for backwards compatibility reasons?

Comment: Its a know break in VS. Just use std::runtime_error and it will work the same (as std::runtime_error is derived from std::exception).

Comment: Done! Are you using some Resharper/FxCop like tool to detect these errors, or do you just remember your stuff?

Comment: Thar comes up quite often here. So easy to remember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use a type template as if it was a type. It isn't - only instantiations of the template are types.

You can easily fix the problem in your case. Your class doesn't need to be a template at all - only its constructor and the `CreateErrorMessage` helper function need to be templates.

Comment: Wow, didn't know a constructor could be a template. Nice catch, it worked right away!

Answer (score 3):

The compiler tells you exactly what the problem is:

> use of class template requires template argument list

You cannot catch every possible exception in a single catch. You have to have one for each different `T`, *or* catch by reference to a common base class.

```
catch (const DRAException& Ex)
```